# Mapping Super Keys to Control without Xmodmap

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've been attempting to switch my super and control keys in X on a macbook and have been half successful. I'd like to avoid creating a custom .Xmodmap if possible, as there is a temporary 100% cpu bug that pops up every time the custom map is loaded (not to mention various warnings against using xmodmap generally which I've come across).

After some diging, I ended up putting Option "XkbOptions" "altwin:ctrl_win" in my 01-keyboard-layout.conf file which has gotten me halfway there: for eg, left command now maps to 133 Control_L. However, the control keys remain the same. Left control, for eg still maps to 37 Control_L.

Looking through evdev.lst (and a bunch of googling) turned up no relevant XkbOption for turning control keys into supers, and now i'm pretty stuck.

I'm now looking through the insanity that is Doug Palmer's [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/xkb.html) but it is, as he describes, a descent into hell.

anyone who's attempted this switchover before and knows the exact rules/symbols/keymaps to get it done, your assistance would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did finally get this to work.

First, these two resources are amazing for anyone wanting to delve into this mess:

http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/ & http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/index.html

For anyone specifically trying to do this switchover, this is what I did:

1) create a file in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols for your new mapping 2) put this in it:

```
// Control is SWAPPED with Win-keys 
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "cmd_n_ctrl" {
    key <LWIN> {        [       Control_L               ]       };
    key <RWIN> {        [       Control_R               ]       };
    key <LCTL> {       [       Super_L         ]       };
    modifier_map Control { <LWIN>, <RWIN> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <LCTL> };
};
```

3: edit evdev in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules to include:

```
altwin2:cmd_n_ctrl               =       +altwin2(cmd_n_ctrl)
```

(under the option = symbols section)

4: add your new option to evdev.lst (same dir):

```
altwin2:cmd_n_ctrl
```

(under the option section)

5: now edit your 01-Keyboard conf file to include the new option that you've created. Mine looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "keyboard-layout"
        Driver "evdev"
        MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us, ru, ca, fr"
        Option "XkbOptions" "altwin2:cmd_n_ctrl"
EndSection
```

6: reboot and you should be good to go.

The above resources are way better at explaining all of this, or any snags you might run into. There is probably a much better way to do this (probably not altering the contents of /usr/share), but so far, this is what got me up and running.

Hope that helps someone else stuck in this spot!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is simpler than the Asker's. (Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Dell.)

1) In the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`, swap the scan codes (numbers) of the keys you want swapped. NOTE: your hardware may target a different keycode file than `evdev`.

2) Run `sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm` to clear the xkb cache, then reboot.